# Database Server version while upgrading to Sitecore 9

Tags: upgrade, sql-database

I have a few Sitecore instances running on Sitecore 8.2/8.1 with databases on MS SQL 2012 and MongoDB for the xDB.

I want to upgrade this instance to Sitecore 9. As I need MS SQL 2016 for the xDB I would like all databases in that version - eliminating the need for a 2014.. According to the upgrade guide I should be able to update in 1 step.

But, after checking the compatibility table of Sitecore (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164) I think I might have an issue.. as SQL2012 is not supported by Sitecore9, I assume I need to move my databases before upgrading. This should work for the 8.2 ones as that version apparently supports SQL2016 but not for the 8.1.. As I can't find this info in the upgrade guide, are my assumptions correct:

- for an upgrade from 8.2, I first need to move my databases to SQL2016
- for an upgrade from 8.1, I first need to move my databases to SQL2014 and after the upgrade again to SQL2016 (or first upgrade to 8.2)

Comment: From Sitecore perspective, Your assumptions are correct. However, from SQL Server perspective you shouldn't face any issue as SQL 2016 supports 2014 and 2012 databases accordingly to here (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level). Let's see if someone has a different idea.

Comment: Don't forget to use  MS SQL 2016 SP1 as only that release is compatible -> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct process is to upgrade from 8.1 to 9.0 directly and then re-attach the DBs to SQL 2016. The upgrade process is using Sitecore API to install items and is not sensitive to SQL version

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question to Sitecore support when going from 9.0.1 to 9.2 (as they are not cross compatible when it comes to MSSQL server).

Their answer:
Your environment should match all the software requirements listed in installation guide before starting upgrade:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/92/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_92_Initial_Release.aspx

You should upgrade your SQL Server first before you start Sitecore upgrade.